# How to rapidly cache document counts for referenced objects?

Tags: mongodb

I'm caching the counts of referenced documents and finding my method far too slow.

Suppose a simple one-to-many model with comments against posts. I insert some stuff that looks like this:

```
db.posts.insert( { _id:"foo", ncomments:0 } );
db.posts.insert( { _id:"bar", ncomments:0 } );
db.posts.insert( { _id:"baz", ncomments:0 } );

db.comments.insert( { post_id:"foo", comment:"First comment" } );
db.comments.insert( { post_id:"foo", comment:"Second comment" } );
db.comments.insert( { post_id:"bar", comment:"Another comment" } );
```

Now to rebuild all the **ncomments** fields I do this:

```
db.posts.find().forEach( function(post){
    var n = db.comments.find( { post_id: post._id } ).count();
    db.posts.update( { _id: post._id }, { $set : { ncomments: n } } );
} );
```

This works fine until the collection gets large - Taking about a second for every 1,000 documents.

Is there a faster way to do this, perhaps without the iterative script approach?

I'm not asking how I should have structured the data; nor how I should invalidate smaller portions of the cache at once. I'm asking in the given situation what better way is there to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to speed this process up about ten times with the following.

```
// allow application to reduce subset of posts if possible
var query = {};

// index all comment counts by post
var counts = {};
db.comments.aggregate( [
    { $match: query },
    { $group : { 
        '_id' : '$post_id', 
        'num' : { $sum: 1 } 
    } }
] ).forEach( function( group ){
    counts[ group._id ] = group.num;
} );

// for all posts (including those without comments) \
// collect a multi-update batch
var updates = db.posts.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
db.posts.find( query, { _id:1 } ).forEach( function( post ){
    updates.find( { _id: post._id } ).update( { $set: {
        ncomments: counts[ post._id ] || 0
    } } );
} );

// execute all updates with a loose write concern for speed
updates.execute( { w: 0, j: false } );
```

I'm still open to better answers before I accept my own.